# Net use: How can I connect to a network share?

Tags: vb.net, networking, network-programming

(using vb.net)

How can I connect to a network share without using System.Diagnostics.Process.Start?

I need to connect to a network share and get feedback if it already exists.

Can I use some kind of API?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use a native call to mpr.dll to add a connection

http://pinvoke.net/default.aspx/mpr/WNetAddConnection2.html

You provide the function with the localname (aka diskletter) and remotename (the \server\sharename)  in the NETRESOURCE class

A return value of 0 means success, a value of (among many others)

```
const int ERROR_ALREADY_ASSIGNED = 85,
```

(see http://msdn.microsoft.com/nl-be/library/aa385413(v=VS.85).aspx)

means the localname is already in use. If you want to find out if the remotename is already assigned you have to enumerate over the current mappings with the WNetEnumResource

http://pinvoke.net/default.aspx/mpr.WNetEnumResource